# System. InvalidOperationException

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm trying to make a program with a login system
I'm new to this but I have been working 8 hours straight trying to fix this.
This is the error code I get

```
+ ServerVersion 'con.ServerVersion' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'   string {System.InvalidOperationException}
```

Here's my code

```
    private void LogB_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=Myip;user id=MyId;database=MyDb;password=MyPw;persistsecurityinfo=True");
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * From login where navn='"+ TULog.Text + "' and pw='" + TPLog.Text + "'",con);

        try
        {

            con.Open();


        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Sorry If this seems like some crap but I'm a guy who's trying to learn :p

Comment: Can you include the full exception details?

Comment: Move the lines for the adapter, table and fill after the con.Open (inside the try/catch) also search how to write parameterized queries

Comment: ServerVersion 'con.ServerVersion' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' string {System.InvalidOperationException}
Non-Public members
'con.HasLocalTransaction' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'

'con.HasLocalTransactionFromAPI' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'

Answer (score 1):

This exception is telling you that there was an attempt to access the `con.ServerVersion` property while the `SqlConnection` was closed.

From MSDN on the [SqlConnection.ServerVersion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection.serverversion.aspx) property:

> InvalidOperationException - The connection is closed. ServerVersion was called while the returned Task was not completed and the connection was not opened after a call to OpenAsync.

The code you show above does not show a call to this property, you must be doing so somewhere else.  Regardless, the connection needs to be open prior to doing so.

Comment: Like this? This is still not working for me --    
try
            {
                
                con.Open();
                MessageBox.Show("ServerVersion: " + con.ServerVersion + "\nState: " + con.State.ToString());

            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                throw ex;
            }
            finally
            {
                con.Close();
            }

Comment: @TheisJ You must be referencing this property elsewhere, before the connection is open.  I suggest you single step through your program in the debugger to find out which line is throwing the exception.

Comment: @Kgargoosh No I didn't. Stioll trying to solve it :p Sorry for the late answer. 
This is my code rigth now - http://prntscr.com/ev2qmi . I'm desperate to get it working, so I'm trying alot of stuff :)

Comment: @TheisJ run the application in a debugger.  Which line is throwing the exception? I don't think it's the code you have posted.

Comment: http://prntscr.com/evawdn - This is what I get. It can't run line 29 :)

Comment: @TheisJ there is no exception in that screen shot.  Run the debugger until the point the exception occurs, then show that.

Comment: It's in danish but the most of that you can read http://prnt.sc/evc9ys -  @Khargoosh

Comment: @TheisJ this is a totally different exception to the one you described above.  The screenshot indicates a `SqlException` at the `SqlConnection.Open()` method call.  Read the MSDN docs for this exception on the Open() method, also [take a look here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_protocols/2007/03/31/named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server/).